# Why won't my FTP server let me upload?

Tags: server, files, ftp, upload

I am using ubuntu server with FTP, and I don't have permision to upload files. I think this is because of ubuntu, How do i change the permisions of files on ubuntu server? 12.04.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. But it turns out the problem was in the `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file. You have to uncomment the `write_enable=YES` line. Or just make sure it says `YES` and not `NO`. That is what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I would need to know where the files are, but this is an example:

user: **alex**
folder: **/home/ftp/alex**

```
sudo chown -R root:alex /home/ftp/alex
sudo chmod -R 774 /home/ftp/alex
```

That should give you enough permissions to do what you need.

Comment: perfect , thank you , its still for 10 years ago the perfect answer